# How to initialize the array in default constructor C++?

Tags: c++

So my edited question is:

My .h file is:

```
#ifndef FUNC
#define FUNC

using namespace std;

class func{
public:
    double time[100];
    double y_output[100];
    func();
    double expression(double t ,double y);
    void rk4();


};

#endif
```

My .cpp file is

```
#include"func.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;
func::func(): time{}, y_output{5} {} //tried this from one of the answers posted below.

double func::expression(double t, double y)
{
    return (t+y)*sin(t*y);
}
void func::rk4()
{
    float h = 0.2;
    double k0,k1,k2,k3;
    for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++)
    {
       k0 = (h*func::expression((time[i]),(y_output[i])));
       k1 = (h*func::expression((time[i]+(h/2)),(y_output[i]+(k0/2))));
       k2 = (h*func::expression((time[i]+(h/2)),(y_output[i]+(k1/2))));
       k3 = (h*func::expression((time[i]+h),(y_output[i]+(k2/2))));
       y_output[i+1] = y_output[i] + (k0+k1+k2+k3)/6;
       time[i+1] = time[i] + h;

    }
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Reema\Desktop\ritikaS\RK4\func.cpp|6|error: mixing declarations and function-definitions is forbidden|
```

I am not sure how to initialize the array's first element. Could anyone help me with it?

Another approach:

I just tried another method. I initialized the value manually from the main without creating a constructor in the class myself and it worked. 
main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "func.h"
#include "func.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    func f;
    double a = 5;
    double b = 0;
    f.y_output[0] = a;
    f.time[0] = b;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I was wondering if the array could be initialized inside the constructor. Could anyone help me with the idea?

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] of your code that doesn't work?

Comment: it would help us if you post a [MRE]

Comment: `func::func() { y_output[0] = 5; }`

Comment: Try doing [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qn4rZb)

Comment: @Jarod42 That's not a temporary.

Comment: `func() { double time[100] = {};}` creates a local variable (unrelated to your member) which ends at end of constructor scope.

Comment: I have uploaded my edited question. Even though I have initialized my array in main function, is there a way to initialize inside the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to initialize the y_output[0] = 5.

You do it like this:

```
func::func(): time{}, y_output{5} {}
```